# SQL Server Wants to Create and Then Drop A Clustered Index While Creating Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to partition a table with a clustered index in which the primary key is an identity field.  When SQL Server creates the script to partition the table, it creates the clustered index in the script - then immediately drops it.  Can anyone think of a scenario in which that would occur?  Just to note, we have a workaround solution to this.  I am just trying to understand why SQL Server is behaving this way.  Any insights would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Refer - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c72a883-2f89-4eef-a8ca-57ddb1210986/understanding-the-script-generated-by-the-partition-wizard

Comment: The designer generated scripts are often suboptimal. This is not surprising at all. Still, a valid questions.

Answer (score 1):

A partitioned index (a primary key) is partitioned the same manner as the table. By default, when you partition an existing table, the primary key will be dropped and recreated. This makes the index aligned with the table. Hope it helps

Comment: The strange thing is that SQL Server wants to create the clustered index and then drop it entirely.  I am not understanding why....I would expect that the index be dropped and recreated, but not the reverse?

Comment: You could manually drop the index and re-creat after you partitioned the table.

Comment: @Hlin...thanks.  We do have a workaround for this.  I was curious about why SQL Server was behaving this way in the first place.  I wasn't expecting it to drop an existing clustered index as part of its script.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the clustered index's main purpose is to physically organize the pages of a table. And because this clustered index's key was not the part of the primary key hence later on it drops.